# Insert / and reverse the yymmdd to ddmmyy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(hello.csv)
print (df)

20101201
20101202
20101203
20101204
20110101
20110102
```

1)I want to insert / between year ,month and date.
2) I want to reverse the yymmdd
to ddmmyy

Output should be like this

```
01/12/2010
02/12/2010
03/12/2010
04/12/2010
01/01/2011
02/01/2011
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('hello.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following. Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function of pandas and mentioning regex in it to catch the values in capturing groups which later I am re-shuffling as per required output.

```
df['date'].astype(str).replace(r'^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$',r'\3/\2/\1',regex=True)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
01/12/2010
02/12/2010
03/12/2010
04/12/2010
01/01/2011
02/01/2011
```